# Noah's Ark found in Turkey

Tags: religion

Claim: The site designated by the Turkish government in Ararat is the actual Noah's Ark from the bible.

I recently viewed a documentary about how Noah's Ark was discovered in Turkey in the 60's following cold war satellite images.  After some investigation, the excitement died down.  However, in the 1980's further investigation revealed petrified wood, and metal (rivets/bolts/etc) aligned along lines that would be expected of a ship.  Turkey has declared the site the "official" resting place of Noah's Ark.  Here's one article:

https://www.israelhayom.com/2021/10/04/archaeologists-claim-to-have-found-true-location-of-noahs-ark/

What are your thoughts? Has this been debunked?

Comment: Welcome Night O. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance as to our ways. You'll find that the search facility at the top would have lead you to discover that this question has [already been asked and answered here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6573/has-noahs-ark-been-discovered-in-turkey).

Comment: Thanks for the reference.  One thing I also learned is that many scholars, including religious ones, claim that IF the Flood and the Ark were real, it will never be found because Noah's family would have had no choice but to dismantle it and use it for building materials and firewood as there would be no trees.

Comment: @NightOwl: "many scholars, including religious ones" Not many non-religious scholars even concede there was a Great Flood, let alone an ark carrying all the terrestrial biomass. So, it is unlikely that many of them have considered one particular logistical issue and not all the others than reject the myth as nonsense. Please provide a reference.